# Dynamically create async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am wondering if it is possible to dynamically create an async function like this:

```
new Function('await Promise.resolve()');
```

Expectedly, the previous code throw:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Comment: Of course it comes with the caveat that you should really never do this, but I think it's a very valid question :)

Comment: Why would you need to create a function like that?

Comment: You can always do `new Function('return async function() { ... }')()`.

Comment: @FelixKling, you give the best solution, unfortunately I cannot accept a comment as answer

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you can get a reference to the non-global [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction) constructor to dynamically create async functions.

You get a reference to the AsyncFunction constructor like this:

```
const AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor;
```

The signature of the AsyncFunction constructor is:

```
AsyncFunction(arg0?, arg1?, ...args?, functionBody: string);
```

NOTE: The `AsyncFunction` contructor is **not** global (like `Function` is), the only way to get a reference to it is via the prototype of an `async function(){}` instance, as shown above and in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction).

---

### Example 1. Simple function without parameters:

```
    const AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor;
    
    const myAsync = new AsyncFunction(`return true`);
    
    const result = await myAsync(); // true
    
    myAsync().then((result) => {
        // result is true
    });
```

The example above is equivalent to:

```
    const myAsync = async () => {
        return true;
    };
```

---

### Example 2. Defining parameters:

```
    const AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor;
    
    // Define two named arguments: inValue, delay
    const asyncFn = new AsyncFunction('inValue', 'delay', `return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {resolve(inValue)}, delay);
    });`);
    
    // resolves to 'hello' after 100ms
    const result = await asyncFn('hello', 100);
    
    // After 200ms the promise will be resolved with the value 'world'
    asyncFn('world', 200).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

The example above is equivalent to:

```
    const asyncFn = async (inValue, delay) => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {resolve(inValue)}, delay);
        });
    };
```

Another cool thing is that the parameters are allowed to use defaults, destructuring, and rest parameters.

```
    const AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor;
    
    // Define defaults for inValue and delay
    const asyncFn = new AsyncFunction('inValue = "Hello"', 'delay = 100', `return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {resolve(inValue)}, delay);
    });`);
    
    // resolves to 'hello' after 100ms (because we defined default parameters)
    const result = await asyncFn();
    
    // resolves to 'world' after 200ms
    const result = await asyncFn('world', 200);
```

---

### Example 3. Higher-level function constructor

Just note that it might be insecure to construct a function like this if the `delay` value were to come from an untrusted source, like user input.

```
    const AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor;
    
    function createAsync(delay){
        return new AsyncFunction('inValue', `return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {resolve(inValue)}, ${delay});
        });`);
    }
    
    const asyncFn = createAsync(100);
    const asyncFn2 = createAsync(200);
    
    // After 100ms this will resolve 'hello'
    await result1 = asyncFn('hello');
    
    // After 200ms this will resolve 'world'
    await result2 = asyncFn2('world');
```

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
    function createAsync(delay){
        return async (inValue) => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {resolve(inValue)}, delay);
            };
        };
    }
    
    const asyncFn = createAsync(100);
    
    // After 100ms this will resolve 'hello'
    await result1 = asyncFn('hello');
    
    // After 100ms this will resolve 'world'
    await result2 = asyncFn('world');
```

And remember that you can use `await` inside the dynamically created async function :)

Note that the same security considerations apply to the async function constructor as the `Function` constructor and `eval()`.

If you are constructing a new function with content received from an untrusted source then your script or application may be vulnerable
to injection attacks.

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(async function(){}).constructor` works in navigator console but in a React component context it gives a regular `f Function () { [native code] }`

Comment: You would have to check your build settings, if you're having to support old/legacy runtimes then babel might be transpiling your `async function(){}` literal down to a regular function. You might need to check the generated js output to know if that is happening - but otherwise there is nothing special about React components that would prevent this from working.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `new Function()`. I'd personally say NEVER use it unless you're a compiler because:

1. It's ugly
2. Code in strings is sooo 90s.. and it's ugly

Creating functions dynamically in js simply requires you to declare a function expression:

```
function functionMaker() {
    return function () {};
}
```

Therefore creating an async function dynamically is simply:

```
function asyncMaker() {
     return async function () {};
}
```

Comment: Nice, however cannot do the same as, is not the same as "new Function()". You missed the goal if you cannot notice any difference.

Comment: So how do I create a function from arbitrary code in a string variable? I mean that is the whole point of new Function()

Comment: @Perry You completely avoid situations where you have code in strings. Needing to create a function from an arbitrary string should be considered a bug. Not doing it, needing it. The thought in your brain considering the idea should be considered a bug.

Answer (score -2):

Use the `new Function()` syntax whit a return inside

```js
async function foo() {
    return await new Promise(next => {
        setTimeout(()=> next('hello there!!'), 3000)
    })
}

var new_async = new Function(`return ${foo.toString()}`)()
console.log(new_async.toString())
```